# Relative input but global movement in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a spaceflight game in unity and stumbled across this simple logical error. I want to be able to add relative movement to my spaceship, but also for it to keep the momentum in that direction when you turn. I've sot a separate script for looking around and movement. Here is my movement source code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController ship;

    public float speed = 0.001f;

    float momentum = 0f;
 
    Vector3 velocity;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update()
    {

            momentum = momentum + Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            

            Vector3 move = transform.forward *  momentum * 0.001f;

            ship.Move(move);

    }
}
```

I know this is a simple question, my brain is just kind of stuck right now. Thanks! ~OwenPT

Comment: Maybe try addForce()?

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that you want the spaceship fly forward and when it turns right or left it must continue flying forward?

Your spaceship must have component rigidbody (I think it does) and you get mode him using function [GetComponent().AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html). There you can choose the [ForceMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html_). There are 4 kinds of force_mode:

1. Force - Add a continuous force to the rigidbody, using its mass.
2. Acceleration - Add a continuous acceleration to the rigidbody, ignoring its mass.
3. Impulse - Add an instant force impulse to the rigidbody, using its mass.
4. VelocityChange -     Add an instant velocity change to the rigidbody, ignoring its mass.

So, choose the one you need and the spaceship must continue flying forward after turning

Answer (score 0):

You've neglected your `velocity` variable.  You're applying a scalar speed (`momentum`) in the direction of facing (`transform.forward`).

If you want to have a feel of momentum, you *need* to deal with Acceleration:

```
public CharacterController Ship;
public float AccelerationFactor = 1.0f;
public float BrakingFactor = 0.1f;
public float MaxSpeed = 20.0f;
private Vector3 Velocity;

void Update()
{
    var totalBraking = Velocity.normalized * BrakingFactor;
    var totalAcceleration = transform.forward * AccelerationFactor * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Velocity = Velocity + (totalAcceleration + totalBraking) * Time.deltaTime;
    Velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(Velocity, MaxSpeed);

    Ship.Move(Velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```